# Is there a special way to use Random.Next inside a class in c# or am i just missing something basic?

Tags: c#

I am new to programming so I am making a rock paper scissors program for practice in c# and I can't make the computer opponent work. I made a new Random object but afterword everything stoped working even Console.WriteLine. It showed an "IDE 1007" error. What do I need to change? Sorry if the question is unclear or if it is too basic.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace _10_21_2020_Rock_paper_scissors
{
    class ComPlayer
    {
        Random randPlay = new Random();
        int comFinPlay;
        comFinPlay = randPlay.Next( 0 , 2);//this is all error IDE1007
        string[] comOptions = { "Rock", "Paper", "Scissor" };
       Console.WriteLine(comOptions[comFinPlay]);//this is all error IDE1007
    } 
}
```

Comment: You have no method here, you are trying to add code directly to the class.. Encapsulate your code into a method. Also make sure you leave this line `Random randPlay = new Random();` in the actual class.

Comment: See this [Methods in (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/methods)

Comment: Also, your `Next` should have the bounds `0 - 3` E.g  `randPlay.Next(0,3)` as the upper bounds are exclusive. see this  https://dotnetfiddle.net/IWkbRM

Answer (score 5):

The first problem is you have pasted code into a class. Classes can't have executable statements, they can only have class members, i.e. properties, fields, methods etc.

```
public class ComPlayer
{
    public void MyMethod()
    {
        // your method code
    }
}
```

Heading off the second problem before you get to it. You should only declare Random once (or per thread). In regards to the former, the easiest way to achieve  this is make it an *instance member* (like a field), and/or `static`

```
public class ComPlayer
{
    // I have chosen static for this example
    private static Random _rand = new Random();
    public void MyMethod()
    {
        // your method code
    }
}
```

To make this more thread resilient (if this was in a multithreaded environment), you would mark it with [`ThreadStatic`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threadstaticattribute?view=netcore-3.1) attribute or use a [`ThreadLocal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadlocal-1?view=netcore-3.1)

The third problem you have is the values you are using for [`Next(Int32, Int32)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.next?view=netcore-3.1#System_Random_Next_System_Int32_System_Int32_). The upper bounds are exclusive, which means it needs to be one higher then the actual highest number you want to generate

> Returns a random integer that is within a specified range.
>
> - **minValue** : The inclusive lower bound of the random number returned.
> - **maxValue** : **The exclusive upper bound** of the random number returned. maxValue must be greater than or equal to minValue.

```
public void MyMethod()
{
    ...

    comFinPlay = _rand.Next(0, 3); 

    ...
}
```

So your full class may look something like this (further liberties taken)

```
public class ComPlayer
{
   private static readonly Random _rand = new Random();
   private static readonly string[] _options = {"Rock", "Paper", "Scissor"};

   public void MyMethod()
   {
      int comFinPlay = _rand.Next(0, _options.Count);
      Console.WriteLine(_options[comFinPlay]); 
   }
}
```

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mrVOKZ)

---

**Additional Resources**

- [Methods in (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/methods)
- [Classes (C# Programming Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/classes))
- [Static Classes and Static Class Members (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members)
- [Random.Next(Int32, Int32)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.next?view=netcore-3.1#System_Random_Next_System_Int32_System_Int32_)
- [readonly (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/readonly)
- [The System.Random class and thread safety](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=netcore-3.1#ThreadSafety)

Comment: It actually needs `[ThreadStatic] private static Random _rand = new Random();` to be created once per thread.

Comment: @Enigmativity yup indeed correct, though id make a conscious decision to leave that out. maybe I should add for utter completeness. Thanks

Comment: Further considerations: You'll want to be able to check later if the computer's choice wins or loses against the player's choice. Think about returning a number value from `MyMethod()` by changing it to `public int MyMethod()` and returning the number that you randomly generated, then testing that against a number that the player chose! `0` could represent rock, `1` is paper, and `2` is scissors. You could even create an Enum to store those values, but that might be too much for just starting to learn. Good luck!